# Word in message box appears in a different line

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following VBA to open a message box:

```
Sub Message()
MsgBox ("Do you want create a file on your desktop?" _
& vbCr & " " _
& vbCr & "Once you click yes an unprotected file with all sheets visible will be saved on your desktop and opened. You can immediately start working with this file.")
End Sub
```

All this works fine.

---

[image]

However, as you can see in the screenshot the word "file" goes in a different line. Is it possible to format the `messagebox` or change the `VBA` code so the word "file" does not appear in a different line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the resolution of the PC of the user. In my case I even get it like this:

[image]

If you want to control the lines, then you should write a custom form. There you would have much better control over the display, and if you play a bit with its properties, you would mimic exactly the `MsgBox()`:

[image]

Some sample code, `Label1` is a label element:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.Label1 = "Do you want create a file on your desktop?" _
            & vbCr & " " _
            & vbCr & "Once you click yes an unprotected file with all sheets visible will be saved on your desktop and opened." & _
            vbCrLf & "You can immediately start working with this file."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps adjust your code with line breaks to suit. For example:

```
Sub Message()
MsgBox ("Do you want create a file on your desktop?" _
& vbCr & " " _
& vbCr & "Once you click yes an unprotected file" _
& vbCr & " " _
& vbCr & "with all sheets visible will be saved on your desktop and opened." _
& vbCr & " " _
& vbCr & "You can immediately start working with this file.")
End Sub
```